# Draggable with ghosting in jquery-ui not working in IE8/9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

Starting by simply generating a draggable box, and a handle at the top using jquery-ui draggable().

However, sometime the content inside of the box can be flash and this tends to cause the dragging function to move too slowly. I decided to move to a ghosting type system where you drag it and it shows a box where you are moving it, and then moves it to the location you drop this.

I have gotten it running perfectly in Chrome/Firefox, but cannot get it to run in either IE8 or IE9. Wondering if anyone had any suggestions. Below is the jquery specific code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$container = $('#container');
$container.draggable({
    handle: "#header",
    containment: "parent",
    scroll: false,
    helper: function () {
        return "<div class='dragbox' style='width:" + ($container.width()) + "px;height:" + ($container.height()) + "px'></div>";
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        var top = ui.position.top,
            left = ui.position.left;
        $container.css({
            'top': top + "px",
                'left': left + "px"
        });
    }
});
});
```

Example can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/Ep5wu/.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The argument 'ui' in drag stop event is the element that is dragged itself and not the the 'helper' div (green box) .. you need the top/left values of the 'helper' after the drag stops.

Try this ..works in IE10

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $container = $('#container');
        $container.draggable(
        {
            handle: "#header", scroll: false,       
            helper:function () {
                return "<div class='dragbox' style='width:" + ($container.width()) + "px;height:" + ($container.height()) + "px'></div>";
            },
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                console.log(ui.helper);
                var top = $(ui.helper).offset().top;
                var left = $(ui.helper).offset().left;
                $container.css({
                    'top': top + "px",
                    'left': left + "px"
                });
        }
            });
    });
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ep5wu/16/